# Prevent users copying Android app content

Tags: android

I have an android application that helps users to read some  books , it is in pdf format.When users choose a book from a list , that book just downloaded from the server and users can read it.

I want to prevent users from copying the pdfs from the app. is it possible?

Help is highly appreciable

Thanks,

Comment: You can use encryption to prevent illegal use of your files .

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you decypher the pdfs on the device, it means the device owner has the code to decrypt pdf files. A good and motivated hacker will always be able to find that code and decypher the books. There is no solution against that.

Nevertheless, piracy and anti-piracy is some kind of nuclear weapon race, so do you best to make things more difficult for hackers, use several custom encryption schemes for instance. Also you can consider using KeyChain to store your decyphering keys : http://nelenkov.blogspot.fr/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html

But still, a good hacker with time would find a way. Also, if you are looking for some legal answer more than a technical one, your licence should explicitly prevent people from decyphering the files.

Answer (score 0):

Simple method is you can convert it into a byte array, encode it base 64, and store it in shared preference as a string. when the user opens it, you can decode and display

Answer (score -1):

It will be illegal from the case of copyright. you can do it using free books or pdfs.